# How can I make my own Scheduler class just like GXT scheduler using GWT and Sencha GXT?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

We are trying to make a resource management application in GWT. But we need some kind of scheduler for that. GXT scheduler is a good resource management tool but it is a paid tool. So I was wondering if we could make our own scheduler using GWT and GXT any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can make anything you can think of using GWT. You need to be more specific: tell us what you have tried and which problems you have encountered. Then we can help.

Comment: <http://www.gxt-scheduler.com/explorer/index.html#ExamplePlace:timeaxis> We have to make our UI look like the link above mentioned. First we tried using GWT-cal but it doesnt have any resource view. Also, dropping appointments into the calendar from outside the calendar didnt work. how have they built the scheduler, left column that displays resources seems like a normal grid column but the actual scheduler on the right side, how is that built?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement something similar using a regular DataGrid or a [custom DataGrid](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid). Each column in a grid will represent a time slot (day, week or month). You can change background of cells to different colors as needed. The advantage of using a DataGrid is that you can capture various browser events, like clicks on a cell, mouse-over, etc. It also automatically aligns resources with time periods (same row).

[image: DataGrid sample]

This is an image from my app, which is a standard DataGrid. I needed dots for this design, but you can use a different CSS to create seamless lines.